# Is this true? $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-1\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-1\right)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(1\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

Is this statement about Grandi's series true?
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( -1 \right )^{n}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( -1 \right ) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( 1 \right )
$$

I was playing with infinite sums, and I noticed that since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( -1 \right )^{n}$ is just 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1..., and can be separated into two series. I know that Grandi's series is divergent, but can it still be a sum of two other series?

Comment: The right hand side is equal to $-\infty+\infty$, which we do not define. For more, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: Why downvoting a question like this ? And without proper comments? And for a new contributor as well ?

Comment: @Thomas Because it doesn't show any research effort ("I was playing with infinite sums") and it is unclear (what does the identity you ask about mean?).

Answer (score 3):

There is no infinite grouping of terms allowed if a series is divergent. So you can not write a divergent series as a sum of two other divergent series.

Comment: In general, we can only do grouping if the series converges absolutely.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not true in any meaningful sense.

The series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( -1 \right )^{n}$ has (Cesaro, Dirichlet) regularized value of $-1/2$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( -1 \right )$ has (Dirichlet) regularized value of $-1/2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }1$ has regularized value $1/2$. So, the right hand side has regularized value of $0$ (regularization is a linear operator), and the left-hand side has the regularized value of $-1/2$, so they cannot be equal.

Comment: I am not sure that the OP can understand your answer. Given the algebraic manipulations he proposes he is learning now about series convergence. Still your answer can be useful for other users, but a reference to/discussion of this series regularization technique would help, in my opinion...